# Проблема с линковкой GLEW в QT

Tags: c++, c, qt, opengl, link

Использую QT Creator 4.2.1, glew-2.0.0.

Имеется main.cpp

```
#define GLEW_STATIC 1

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void) {
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewInit();

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    /* Render here */
    static const GLfloat red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Так же имеется файл .pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -L"C:/Software/Programming/glew-2.0.0/lib/Release/Win32/" -lglew32 -lGLFW3 -lopengl32 -luser32 -lgdi32
```

Dll файл glew.dll закинул в system32, lib и include папки смерджил с соответствующими папками в директории mingw.

Собрать проект не получается, выводится следующее:

```
C:\projects\Qt\QMAKE_TEST\main.cpp:30: ошибка: undefined reference to       "__glewClearBufferfv"
```

В чем проблема и что я делаю не так?

Comment: вобще никакого смысла нет использовать `QT` вместе с `GLFW` - эти библиотеки оба обеспечивают кроссплатформенное создание окон (в случае с `QT` вдобавок ещё куча всего, так как это фреймворк). Так что совет - выберите что-то одно ... да вам даже glew не нужен если есть `QT`, так как с `OpenGL` он может работать из "коробки"

Comment: GLFW позволяет просто создать окно и сделать ввод данных, а в QT я такого не видел.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, заменив библиотеку -lglew32 на -lglew32s.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы написали, почему это помогло.

Comment: @vp_arth скорее всего из-за того, что приложение линкуется статически (`#define GLEW_STATIC 1`) а для этого нужен как раз `-glew32s`